# Different linking behavior depending on how a go binary is run

Tags: go

I want to add a `cobra` command to my `go` cli tool that just prints the version

```golang
var version = "development"

// versionCmd prints mytool version
var versionCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "version",
    Short: "Print mytool version information",
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {

        fmt.Println("mytool version", version)
        return nil
    },
}
```

I can override (or choose not to do so) the `version` variable using `ldflags`

```
▶ go build

▶ ./mytool version
mytool version development

▶ go build -ldflags "-X github.com/myprofile/mytool/cmd.version=$(git describe --tags --always)"

▶ ./mytool version                                                                             
mytool version cffc487
```

However, when performing `go install` the behavior changes, I can't seem to be able to override the `version` var, why is that?

```
▶ go build -ldflags "-X github.com/myprofile/mytool/cmd.version=$(git describe --tags --always)"

▶ go install                                                                                  

▶ ~/go/bin/mytool version                                                                      
mytool version development
```

Using

```
▶ go version
go version go1.14 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: You didn't set `-ldflags` during `go install`, hence it's not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `go build` creates a binary and saves it. Your `go install` *creates a new binary and saves it to* `GOPATH/bin`. `go install` does not make any use of the binary created previously by `go build`. If you want to specify version values in your `go build`, you should distribute the resulting binary rather than encouraging users to use `go install`.

Alternatively, you can specify `ldflags` in your `go install` command, but that's probably pretty cumbersome for end-users - they're not going to care enough about having it output the correct version string to bother with the much longer command.